# convert from arraylist to 2d array (return reference)

Tags: java

I have a problem converting from arraylist to a 2d array.

in this code the return value is the reference not value

```
public int[][] convertTO2D(java.util.List<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayList){

    int listSize = arrayList.size();
    int[][] darr = new int[listSize][];
    for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> sublist = arrayList.get(i);
        int sublistSize = sublist.size();
        darr[i] = new int[sublistSize];
        for(int j = 0; j < sublistSize; j++) {
            darr[i][j] = sublist.get(j);
        }
       // System.out.println("");
    }

    return darr;
}
```

and the this is the output of return

```
[[I@5b273190, [I@740ac748, [I@314e4266, [I@1ea46732, [I@7ced7ec7, [I@5effd695]
```

how can I fix that ??

Comment: So you aren't converting your return to a `String`.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code and check how it is executing.

Answer (score 2):

How do you print a 2d array?
use this one `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));`

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see something like `[I@5b273190` coming from a println() statement, it usually means that you are printing a reference to an object, not the contents of the object.

In this instance, you can either iterate through each of your nested arrays printing the values separately (if you want to perform custom formatting), or you can use the method suggested by @vagueness:

> System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29

Comment: I slove the problem thnks . just I add Arrays.deepToString